# org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present:

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

I want to upload a file from my local without using Auto it tool. So i used `Action event` to click on Browse button. I am sending path of the file using `sendKeys` by following code:

```
"driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("path of file");"
```

I am getting `"org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: "` error .

I couldnot handle this exception.

Please anyone could help me in doing this...

Comment: i think there is a pop up and u need to close this before sendkeys.

Comment: elements may being populated. try with a)driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

(or)b)

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ELEMENT_ID"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the alert you are getting before sending keys. You can do it this way:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
// Prints text and closes alert
System.out.println(alert.getText());
alert.accept(); // or alert.dismiss();
```

or if you don't need the message you can just do

```
alert.accept();
```

**EDIT**

Another way you can do this, is wrap your code inside a try-catch:

```
try{
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("path of file");
} catch(UnhandledAlertException e){
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  alert.accept();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("path of file");
}
```

This is clearly a dirty solution but you can use it to check if the code above works for you. Then you can clean it up yourself, according to your needs.

Comment: Hi Aurasphere ,Thanks for ur answer..I tried this alert also but it is not handling .Error message like "there is not alert present" is showing in console

Comment: Same error is displaying "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: "

Comment: This is very strange. I suspect the problem is that whenever you close your alert, another pops up. Could you check this manually? Also, could you report back more info about the alert you are getting? Thank you.